# Cut and Paste looping w/ VBA help needed

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm hoping you can assist me with creating a VBA macro. I have a spreadsheet that has some formatting errors that I'm attempting to fix. I want to look for an empty range of cells (in the provided example, E6:H6). If the range is empty, I want to cut part of the data from the row directly below it (B7:E7) and paste it in E6.

Example Spreadsheet

[image]

I've got the code to do this, however I can't figure out how to loop the macro to continue looking for additional instances. Here's the VBA I have so far.

```
Sub Range_Cut()

Range("B7:E7").Cut Range("E6:H6")

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You mean "...paste it in `E6:H6`", right?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specific to your use case, but it should work. More effort could be applied to making the ranges fully qualified and dynamic.

```
Sub testLoop()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("E:E"))

    For Each c In rng

        If c.Value = "" And c.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then
            c.Offset(1, -3).Resize(1, 4).Cut c
        End If

    Next c

    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

It goes through column E looking for blank cells where there is a value in D. when it finds one, it cuts the offset range from the row below and pastes it in E. Then at the end it deletes the empty rows.

Comment: This worked flawlessly; thank you! I didn't think to look for a value in the D column. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Dim C As Range
For each c in activesheet.range("a2:a17").cells
    if len(c.value) = 0 then c.offset(0, 1).resize(1, 4).cut _
           c.offset(-1, 4)
next c
```